# How to cite a reference in the title of a definition?

Tags: citing, environments

I want to cite a reference just after the definition's number and before ".", so that it is displayed like "Definition 5 [1].". If I use the command \begin{definition}  \cite{}, then it gives "Definition 5. [1]".

I would be grateful if you can help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{user}
{}
{}
{\normalfont}
{}
{\bfseries}
{.}
{2ex}
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ \textnormal{#3}}}
\theoremstyle{user}
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{defin}[\cite{a}]
Text
\end{defin}
\begin{defin}
Text
\end{defin}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{a} Text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oy! Somehow, the existence of the `\newtheoremstyle` command had escaped my notice! That's quite handy.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It works.Thank you very much.